# How do I use the new iOS 9.2 Touch ID feature of "sequential finger detection"

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, touch-id, ios9.2

From the [release notes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW1)

> Support for reusable Touch ID matches. A match from the previous phone unlock can be used by evaluateAccessControl: and evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:.

To me this means that an event CAN be fired if a different finger is being used.

**Abstract Example:**

1. Login with finger 1, and again with finger 1, and again.  No event.
2. If finger 2 is used, event raised.  Subsequent usage of finger 2 no event.

I do fully agree that I won't know what finger was used, just that a *different* one was used.  This informaton might give me enough information to act upon.

**Use Case**

I'm creating an app to assist in domestic violence situations where if a victim is asked to unlock the touch-ID enabled app, and a different finger is used, then the call for help is discreetly erased from the app.

**Research**

This is [not documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014498) on Apple's site outside of release notes, and Diffs however it is present within [Xamarin's site](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/LocalAuthentication.LAContext.EvaluateAccessControl/p/Security.SecAccessControl/LocalAuthentication.LAAccessControlOperation/System.String/System.Action%7BSystem.Boolean/Foundation.NSError%7D/).  I followed up with the [developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/101460?et=watches.email.thread#101460) and don't want to wait for the documentation bug to be acknowledged.

In my scenario, a device is shared between an Adult and a Child, both who are enrolled in TouchID.  I need to determine if a different finger is being used to protect sensitive settings.

**Question**

How do I use [LocalisedReasonReply](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/LocalAuthentication.LAContext.EvaluateAccessControl/p/Security.SecAccessControl/LocalAuthentication.LAAccessControlOperation/System.String/System.Action%7BSystem.Boolean/Foundation.NSError%7D/) to determine if a different finger was used to unlock a phone?  (or am I misunderstanding the new feature)

```
[Foundation.Export("evaluateAccessControl:operation:localizedReason:reply:")]
public virtual Void EvaluateAccessControl (SecAccessControl accessControl,LAAccessControlOperation operation, String localizedReason, [ObjCRuntime.BlockProxy(typeof(ObjCRuntime.Trampolines/NIDActionArity2V1))]Action`2 reply)
```

For reference, I [pasted the LAContext.h file here](http://pastebin.com/VUGhhHYD)

Comment: I don't have a reference, but I don't think this feature means what you think it does. I believe it's a much more simple situation in which your authentication can bypass the user's requirement of touching the sensor if they have recently authenticated using touch id. I.e., "sequential" here meaning sequential requests to authenticate the user, not a sequence of fingers being used to authenticate with.

Comment: @mah I thought that feature you describe existed in older versions as well...

Comment: You do realise that the release notes you are quoting from are the 9.0 release notes, not 9.2? And I agree with @mah, I don't quite see how that description would match the feature you're after. The 9.0 API Diffs that includes `-[LAContext evaluateAccessControl:operation:localizedReason:reply:]` also includes `LAContext.touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration` which does seem to imply that what they mean is indeed that a user doesn't need to touch again if you allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Support for reusable Touch ID matches..." mean that:-

You can re-use device unlock authentication in your app by specifying time interval in  evaluateAccessControl: and evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply: methods.

By using LAContext Property "touchIDAuthenticationAllowableReuseDuration", You can reuse Device Unlock authentication in app, **these is because at a time of device unlock you already authenticate your self. So it not required to authenticate again.(New Introduce iOS 9)**

Note: Time duration must be in seconds. it default value is '0' and you specify duration up to 5 Minutes, beyond 5 minutes does not increase the accepted interval.